# can i use post with retrofit but i don't put any url on @POST

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to post a url likes "https://blog.banned.top:2054" without any subpath, how can i do?

When I run code like this:

```kotlin
//interface
@Multipart
@POST("")
fun updateProfile(
        @Part("tile_mode")
        fullName : Int,
        @Part("raw_image")
        image : RequestBody,
                 ) : Call<Result>
```

```kotlin
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://blog.banned.top:2054")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).build()
val request = retrofit.create(GetRequestInterface::class.java)
val call : Call<Result> = request.updateProfile(some parameter)
```

it will shows wrong code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL host: ""
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1402)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:506)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:19)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```

how can I solve this problem？

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that by simply adding "/" in your post arg

```
//interface
@Multipart
@POST("/")
fun updateProfile(
        @Part("tile_mode")
        fullName : Int,
        @Part("raw_image")
        image : RequestBody,
                 ) : Call<Result>
```